# How do ngfor to set a dynamic function in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this in my html component:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="myFunction1()">myFunction1</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="myFunction2()">myFunction2</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="myFunction3()">myFunction3</button>
</div>
```

and in typescript:

```
myFunction1()
myFunction2()
myFunction3()
```

but i try to do something like this, but it's not working!

typescript component:

```
var myFunctions = [
"myFunction1",
"myFunction2",
"myFunction3"
]
```

html component:

```
<div *ngFor="let myFunction of myFunctions">
    <button (click)="myFunction()">{{myFunction }}</button>
</div>
```

Know someone what the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the function to execute on the button click? Just use the array to hold reference to the functions.

```
// *.ts
const myFunctions = [
  myFunction1,
  myFunction2,
  myFunction3
]
```

Then in your template you can bind the click event to the function.

```
// *.html
<div *ngFor="let myFunction of myFunctions">
    <button (click)="myFunction()">myFunction</button>
</div>
```

Your example above is just binding the click to a string.

Comment: Don't forget to invoke the function in the event handler: `(click)="myFunction()"`.

Comment: good call, i was too greedy with my simplification. answer updated.